# Scrollbar not working on Acer Aspire v5

Tags: windows-8, drivers, touchpad, acer-aspire

I have a new [Acer Aspire V5](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers/-;32505006676;-) (purchased from Acer). I installed Windows 8 in it as been recommended by Acer. Problem is the scrollbar of the touchpad is not working.

I have downloaded synaptic driver from Synaptic web page, also downloaded the Synaptic Driver, ElanPad touchdriver from acer website, nothing is working.

I also went to device manager and uninstalled the pointing device driver, and then updated it from, it does not seem to work.

In the meantime I installed Ubuntu on it, I did not have a problem with the scrollbar in Ubuntu.

Any ideas what else I can do?

Comment: What OS was shipped with the laptop?

Comment: Linux , I don't what flavour of it ; but the guys at the dealership gave me Windows 8 and I had licence of it .

Comment: And are you sure your model is compatible? It just sounds like the drivers do not exist for your version (model) with W8. However, if it was Acer who sold it to you, then you need to get back in touch with them.

Comment: The only OS my laptop has drivers for is Windows 8 64 bit ; I had a licence of Windows 8 from my college , so I had few options than go for Windows 8 .Link for my laptop http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers/-;32505006676;-

Comment: Did you update all drivers (including the chipset)? Either way, you have confused me. You said Windows 8 came from the dealership. You now say you had a copy from your college?

Comment: Also, the link you provide doesn't ship with Unix... So, is that actually the model number?

Comment: I had a licence from my college . If I had to put Windows 8 from the dealership , I had to buy one . I didn't had the money for it . However , Acer has gently provided me a DVD where they have all the drivers . I installed all of them . However , there were two drivers for touchpad , one from Synaptics(used them) , another one from ElanPad(never used). I used every possible trick found on the internet for the scrollbar to work. But no one has posted anything specific Acer Aspire scrollback , hence I am asking for suggestions out here .

Comment: This is funny , but a pic of laptop configuration that is supposed to run windows . http://i.imgur.com/xvkvFPx.jpg

Comment: I'm sorry mate, I really think you need to talk to them direct about this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Acer Aspire is following two finger continuous gesture . Simply by scrolling with two fingers will allow to scroll up and down . This feature is akin to that of Macbook ; even though I haven't used one . But this is definitely different from the last laptop Windows laptop I have used .